# Upgrading from logback 1.2.3 to 1.4.14 to clear security issues. Where to find documentation related to removed classes or interfaces

Tags: logging, logback

I'm trying to upgrade my project from logback 1.2.3 to logback 1.4.14 to clear security issues reported. But see that some of the classes are removed. In my case following are removed.

- ch.qos.logback.core.sift.SiftingJoranConfiguratorBase;
- ch.qos.logback.core.sift.AbstractAppenderFactoryUsingJoran;

What are the alternatives for the same in latest logback 1.4.14 jar?

could not find any documentation which suggest the alternatives for the removed classes.